# Object dynamic property acces in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Sorry if this has been asked/answered previously but I am trying to find how - if possible - to properly use features of TypeScript to dynamically read from properties of an object. I have taken a look at these examples/resources:

- https://codewithstyle.info/Deep-property-access-in-TypeScript/
- https://dmitripavlutin.com/access-object-properties-javascript/
- [Typescript object with known properties dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622646/typescript-object-with-known-properties-dynamically)
- [Dynamic Typescript Object Properties from Function Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334089/dynamic-typescript-object-properties-from-function-arguments)

What I am attempting is most simply described in `attempt #4` in the code (below).

```js
interface Person {
    eyeColor: string,
    hairLength: number,
}

const my: Person = {
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    hairLength: 0,
};

// attempt #1 -------------------
console.log(my.eyeColor) // works just fine
// attempt #2 -------------------
console.log(my['eyeColor']) // works just fine

const eyes = 'eyeColor'
// attempt #3 -------------------
console.log(my[eyes]) // works just fine

const keys: Array<string> = Reflect.ownKeys(my) as Array<string>

// attempt #4 -------------------
keys.forEach((prop) => console.log(my[prop])) // my[prop] does not work
// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Person'.
//   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Person'.(7053)

const pluck = <T, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, prop: P): T[P]|undefined => obj[prop]

// attempt #5 -------------------
keys.forEach((prop) => console.log(pluck(my, prop))) // pluck(my, prop) does not work
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"eyeColor" | "hairLength"'.(2345)

// attempt #6 -------------------
keys.forEach((prop) => {
    const { [prop]: result } = my; // does not work
    // Type 'Person' has no matching index signature for type 'string'.(2537)

    return result
})
```

To restate the question, "What is the proper way to access a property on an object using a variable?"

Comment: Shouldn't `keys` be `Array<keyof Person>`?

Comment: If you are sure that `keys` will not have any unexpected entries (and this is not always obvious) then you can assert `const keys = Reflect.ownKeys(my) as Array<keyof Person>`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes. That fixes my issue. Thank you. I am still fairly new to types and TypeScript. I knew there was a correct way to do what I was I trying I just needed help finding it. If you want to post your answer I will accept it.

Comment: @jcalz thank you as well for answering. This was very helpful.